# Code that will auto sort one of my sheets onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have sheet with 3 columns: Coordinator, Worker, Score.

I would like to automatically sort only one sheet (worker who has got highest score).

I used autotrigger (without if statement) but it worked on all sheets and I do not know how to restrict it to one sheet.

```
function Sortowanie() {
  if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() == 'Name of sheet'){
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
   spreadsheet.getRange('A1:C35').activate();
   spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, 
   spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1).sort({column: 3, ascending: 
   false});
    spreadsheet.getRange('E9').activate();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Explanation

Please see comments in code.

```
function Sortowanie() {

    if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() == 'Name of sheet') {
    // This line is looking at the name of the spreadsheet, not the name of the sheet
    // Use the line below instead

    // if (SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Name of sheet') {
    
        var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
        spreadsheet.getRange('A1:C35').activate();
        // You either need to include the name of the sheet when calling getRange
        // from the Spreadsheet: getRange('Sheet1!A1:C35')
        // Or you need to call getRange from the Sheet:

        /*
        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
        sheet.getRange('A1:C35'),activate();
        etc.
        */

        spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1)
          .sort({column: 3, ascending: false});
        spreadsheet.getRange('E9').activate();
    }
}
```

---

### Minimum Working Code

I'm not sure why you're getting a range and then offsetting it when you could just get the offset range to start with.

```
function sort() {

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();

    if (sheetName === 'Name of sheet') {

        var range = sheet.getRange('A2:C34');

        range.sort({column: 3, ascending: false});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to figure out if you could share your spreadsheet.  But I think this is close.

```
function Sortowanie(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='Name of Sheet'){
    var srg=sh.getRange('A2:C35');
    srg.sort({column: 3, ascending: false});
  }
}
```

- [Range Sort Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))